# Name for the methods of a class which are specifically theirs

Tags: oop, interface, conventions

I have a class which implements several interfaces. I have seen in other places comments being used to indicate which block of methods belong to which interface, such as:

```
public class MagicalAnimal implements InterfaceBark,
                                      InterfaceFly {
    // InterfaceBark
    public void barkQuietly() { }
    public void barkLoudly() { }

    // InterfaceFly
    public void moveWings() { }
    public void land() { }

    // ???
    public void shootLasers() {  }
    public void teleport() {  }
}
```

What would be the comment I should put before listing the methods which are not implemented from any interface but are especific to `MyClass` (indicated in the code as `// ???`)?

Comment: If you show code, you should generaly tag the language. It makes it easier for people to find the questio and it changes syntax highlighting of the code.

Comment: There isn't a standard for this, so just put whatever makes sense to you to document your code.  If you're using a built-in documentation method (like JavaDocs or C#'s XML Comments) then they may have some sort of indicator to determine if it's part of an interface's implementation, but usually you don't need to specify if it's not part of an interface.

Comment: `// These are not the voids you are looking for`

Comment: First of all, the good practice in OOP is to include into a class just the methods declared in its public interfaces. The sense is this: If a class implements interfaces, it should be a direct replacement for any of them. And so, only the interface methods would make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put whatever you want. I recommend putting nothing.

The big concern here is [obsoletion of comments](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1326509), say you put:

```
// Other
```

And then you decide to have an interface

```
public interface MagicPowers {
  public void shootLasers();
  public void teleport();
}
```

Now, you have to remember to change the comment (which *must* be done manually) in addition to adding the interface (which can be done automatically by the IDE).

Most IDEs have the ability to easily see what interface a comment comes from; these comments are not necessary.